# Question about linq query format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, lambda

```
var q = (dc.tblHelpCentreQuestions.Where(c => c.userID == UserID));
q.OrderByDescending(c => c.dateSubmitted);
```

I'm just getting used to Linq, and I'm sorting my records by date submitted descending, but could someone explain to me why I have to do `c => c.dateSubmitted` and not just pass in `tblHelpCentreQuestions.dateSubmitted`?  What does the `c=>` do and why is it needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a lambda expression.  Read about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Also note that OrderByDescending returns a new IEnumerable, it does not do an in-place sort.  You will want to read about Linq basics [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Learn_The_Basics_Of_LINQ.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

q = tblHelpCentreQuestions is enumerable. It does not have dateSubmitted property. Its elements have that property. C stands exactly for that element

Answer (score 1):

the `c=>c.dateSubmitted` is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), they are used a lot with Linq. In this case, it's kind of a selector. it defines which property of your class to order by. `tblHelpCentreQuestions.dateSubmitted` in the other hand is just a "value", it doesn't give info about the property.

Put simply, a lambda expression is an anonymous method. a method needs *parameters*, that's what the `c=>` is for. if you have a method that takes two arguments (say, sender and args), you would have something like `(sender, args)=>`. There are **Expression Lambdas**, which have one expression as their body (as is the case with your example), and **Statement Lambdas** which can have more than one instruction (or statement), and thus need a *block* to delimit it. `(sender, args)=>{ ... }`. It may or may not have a return value.

Hope this helps :)